# Gambling license is mandatory to integrate In app betting for ios apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I did some researching on in app betting,and I have found one framework called as [Betable](https://github.com/betable/betable-ios-sdk) and they says its legal to use in ios apps since they have a gambling license,

My question is **should we have a gambling license to integrate in app betting in our ios apps**? **Will Apple approve if we integrate in app betting in ios apps**?

Is there any other best approaches to achieve in app betting for ios apps? 
your suggestions would be appreciated, thanx in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be best posed to a lawyer in your jurisdiction.

Comment: This is a legal minefield. Take proper legal advice since requirements will change from country to country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to apple's guidlines([REF](http://www.macrumors.com/2013/08/14/apple-releases-new-app-store-review-guidelines-with-updated-info-kids-apps-gambling-app-rules/).), section 20.5 and 20.6. Apple will approve app with gambling integration. But it is dependent on place.

> 20.5 Apps that offer real money gaming (e.g. sports betting, poker, casino games, horse racing) must have necessary licensing and
>   permissions in the locations where the App is used, must be restricted
>   to those locations, and must be free on the App Store
>
> 20.6 Apps that use IAP to purchase credit or currency to use in conjunction with real money gaming will be rejected

Comment: It could be possible to get a gambling license as a service: http://www.curacaowebhosting.com/2018/04/12/license-gambling-app/